# Filter query by related table count

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get a list of people who have at least one family member associated in the database.

`FamilyMembers` is a related table, tied by a one-to-many foreign key.

`[one] People.PersonId --> [0 or more] FamilyMembers.PersonId`

I tried doing this, but `Count()` doesn't seem to work like I thought it would.
I get results containing both 0 and more `FamilyMembers`.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleWithFamilyMembers()
{
    IQueryable<Person> query = Context.Persons;

    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.FamilyMembers.Count());
    query = query.Where(x => x.FamilyMembers.Count() > 0);

    // Execute query and return result:
    return query.Select(x => x);
}
```

I'm really not sure what to do here :-/

Comment: FYI, when using the method syntax you don't need the `Select(x => x)`.

Comment: I know, I put there as a reminder to myself that I need to do something with it later :-) Forgot to remove it when I copy/pasted it here.

Comment: Why not combine those `Where` clauses before the `OrderBy`?  like `.Where(x => x.Deleted != true && x.FamilyMembers.Count() > 0)`.

Comment: I will remove the Deleted != true part from the code here, since it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Michael Why waste time with a join when EF gives you nice navigational properties to work with https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Maybe you need to explicitly make it do a group by.  `Context.Persons.GroupBy(p => p.FamilyMembers.Count()).Where(g => g.Key > 0).OrderBy(g => g.Key).SelectMany(g => g);`

Comment: Also try debugging it and look at the SQL that's being generated.  Maybe that will give you a hint at why it isn't work.

Comment: @juharr yeah I agree, navigation properties is the way to go here! Will remove my comment to not confuse others.

Comment: Do you have lazyloading enabled?

Comment: I'm still rather new at Entity Framework, but to the best of my knowledge, no, I don't have LazyLoading enabled anywhere in this project.

Comment: You really have to look at the generated SQL. It looks like the query should return the correct results. Maybe `FamilyMembers` is tied to the wrong field in `Person` (not `PersonId`)?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a good bit on a elegant solution to this without using expanded query form.

The only way I could achieve this in SQL was using a **Group By** and a **Join**, but I have no idea if I translated it to LINQ correctly. Please feel free to point out my mistakes.

```
var query = Persons
    .Join(FamilyMembers,
        p => p.Id,
        f => f.Id,
        (p,f) => new { Person = p, FamilyMembers = f }
    )
    .GroupBy(g => g.FamilyMembers)
    .Where(w => w.FamilyMembers.Count() > 0);
    .Select(x => new {
        Person = x.Person,
        FamilyMembers = x.Count(y => y.FamilyMembers)
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason, it doesn't like `w.FamilyMembers` in the Where clause. Says `IGrouping<FamilyMember, <anonymous type: Person Person, FamilyMember FamilyMembers>>' does not contain a definition for 'FamilyMembers' and no extension method 'FamilyMembers' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<FamilyMember, <anonymous type: Person Person, FamilyMember FamilyMembers>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: For now, unfortunately, I ran out of time, and had to do it this nasty way. Hope to come back and fix this the proper way later. Not my proudest moment. `query = Context.Persons.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[People] p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[FamilyMembers] f WHERE f.[PersonId] = p.[PersonId] AND (f.[Deleted] = 0 OR f.[Deleted] IS NULL)) > 0").AsQueryable();`